Belief of Nasrani Christians
What were the beliefs of the Syriac Christians in Arabia at the time of the Islamic prophet?
I have heard that these Nazarene Christians (Christians of the city of Najran) did not believe that Jesus was crucified similar to the Muslims. That claim was made by a Christian apologist, but I do not get the angle as the Qur'an clearly mentions that there are Christians who believe that Jesus was crucified as it says about the crucifixion: "it was made to appear to them"

Please, it would be helpful if you had a link or a reference to the "Christian apologetic"

@Wyrsa I believe it was Christian prince but I cannot find the exact video

Interesting, I'm going to improve my answer...

A better answer can be made if you provide a reference to the claim.  Please try to summarize or include a link to the video.  Otherwise, the answer is probably a generic response to the heresy of Docetism / Manichaeism.

As far as I am aware, there is no reason to believe the claim you have mentioned. But let me look. My perspective is that of Eastern Orthodox, which actually matters and my bias will not be hidden.
The Syriac Church is the 2nd established church in history (after Jerusalem), it is mentioned in the book of Acts (Acts 11:26). "The Disciples were first called Christians in Antioch"
It is well documented by Eusebius of Caesarea in Chronicon (I, 2) where he tells us that St. Peter established a bishopric in Antioch...
I see no basis that any Christians of the early church would have denied the resurrection, especially when founded directly by an apostle.

You asked about during the time of the islamic prophet. I'm looking at stuff for the 600s AD period.
The Syriac church (and coptic) was in schism after the 5th century Council of Chalcedon in 451 AD. (The details of the heresy here are not important with regards to giving my answer, but this is where they split away from the One church)
The Syriac church was pressured and by 544 it was in a rather abysmal situation with only 3 heretical bishops remaining.  However it was revitalized in the next 30 years or so by Mor Yacqub Burd`ono. (Jacob Baradeus)

...when the Arabs, who conquered the Near East at the end of the seventh century, wanted to acquire Greek knowledge, they turned to Syriac scholars and churchmen. Arab caliphs commissioned Syriac scholars to translate the sciences of the Greeks into Arabic. In his film Forgotten Christians, Christopher Wenner describes the impact of Syriac scholars and Churchmen when he describes the school at Deir az-Za’faran monastery, “It was through the monks here that the Arabs received Greek learning, and it was the Arabs of course who passed it back to Europe. Had it not been for the Syriac monks, we in Europe might never have had a renaissance.”
The Syriac Orthodox Church survived under the dominion of many empires in the centuries that followed. Under the Arabs, Mongols, Crusades, Mamluks and Ottomans, the Syriac Orthodox Church continued its survival. Neither intimidation nor oppression could suppress the faithful, but the Church diminished in size to a fraction of what it was.

At this point their own website skips forward to the 20th century. And doesn't go into any detail about religious matters.
However I still do not believe that this church denied the resurrection, the heresy that caused the schism was about Christology of what type of Nature Christ had. (the doctrine that Christ has one incarnate nature from two natures; This is heresy from my perspective because it creates a 3rd nature one that is "GodHuman" instead of "Fully Human Fully Divine" which is my belief.


Good, historic evidence you have given here. Educational. Just to point out (in case another reader misunderstands), when you say, "The details of the heresy here are not important" - that means "not important for the purpose of giving my answer to this question." +1
